# KIF not detecting changes in UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, kif, kif-framework

I'm trying to get started writing UI tests using KIF because I want to make sure our navigation flow works.

It seems that KIF is not detecting changes in the `UINavigationController`. I have one view controller in a `UINavigationController` with a `UIButton` titled `Button0`. I have a second view controller with another `UIButton` titled `Button1`. On tap of `Button0`, it navigates to the second view controller. I wrote the following test to verify that the second view controller is being shown:

```
- (void)testTrySomeStuff
{
    [tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Button0"];
    [tester waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Button1"];
}
```

When I present the second view controller modally on button tap, the following test passes. However, if I push it onto the `UINavigationController` stack, the test fails. Is there a workaround for the failure in the case of the `UINavigationController`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Weirdly enough, this was because I was using a UI testing bundle instead of a regular unit testing bundle. Once I switched to a normal testing bundle, the test worked as expected.

Comment: Learned from issue filed here: https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/856